# Error sending POST request from React app to Rocket backend

Tags: javascript, rust, axios, rust-rocket

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to make a POST request from a single page application even though the route works in Postman.

routes.rs

```
#[post("/letters", format = "application/json", data = "<new_letter>")]
fn write_letter(new_letter: Json<NewLetter>, conn: DbConn) -> Json<Value> {
    Json(json!({
        "status": Letter::write(new_letter.into_inner(), &conn),
        "result": null
    }))

}
```

I've got my main.rs set up to allow for CORS

```
let (allowed_origins, failed_origins) = AllowedOrigins::some(&["http://localhost:3000"]);
let options = rocket_cors::Cors {
    allowed_origins: allowed_origins,
    allowed_methods: vec![Method::Get, Method::Put, Method::Post, Method::Delete]
        .into_iter()
        .map(From::from)
        .collect(),
    allowed_headers: AllowedHeaders::all(),
    allow_credentials: true,
    ..Default::default()
};
```

All of the routes work in Postman and the GET requests work from my application. However, when I try to make a POST request from my application, I get a 404 on the front end and the following logged from my backend:

```
OPTIONS /api/letters:
=> Error: No matching routes for OPTIONS /api/letters.
=> Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher.
=> CORS Fairing: Turned missing route OPTIONS /api/letters into an OPTIONS pre-flight request
=> Response succeeded.
```

And here's my front end for reference:

```
writeLetter: (letter) => axios.post(`${base_url}/api/letters`, letter)
  .then(res => {
     if (res.status == 201) {
      console.log("letter successfully submitted")
      return res
    }
    throw new Error(res.error)
  }),
```

Is the problem with how I'm implementing Axios or rocket_cors? I found [one similar issue](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/issues/23) but I seem to be configuring it correctly.

Comment: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/25

Comment: sorry that was just laziness writing the code in here. I updated it

Comment: @Quentin thanks. I'm actually using rocket_cors to get around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was thrown off by how the the OPTIONS route logs. I assumed it was sending a 404 response to the front end because the line `Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher` but two lines underneath it said `Response succeeded` so I dug a little deeper in DevTools.

OPTIONS was sending back a 200 response, and since I was accounting only for a created 201 response, it threw an error.

I updated my API to

```
if (res.status == 201 || res.status == 200) {
  console.log("letter successfully submitted")
  return res
}
```

and that prevented the error from being thrown.